# What happens before Main()?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

The question arrived when I began having some strange symptoms on my computer.

Here's what's happening: I have a WinForms application written in C# (.Net 2.0). If I run it from Visual Studio 2005 (either Debug or Release), everything is just fine. If I try to run it from Windows (run the exact same executable generated by the debug process in VS 2005) I get a 
"`System.TypeInitializationException`" on the Program class.

I have added debug log messages ( `File.AppentAllText()` ) in a static constructor and in Main(). The log messages in the static constructor get written, but the ones in Main() don't. So, clearly, something happens after the static constructor has finished and before the call to Main() is issued.

Any suggestions on where to look next? What happens before the Main() method is called?

Thanks everybody.

***EDIT: I think that I should point out that the application runs just fine on other computers. :)***

Comment: Can you provide the entire exception?

Comment: System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
Message: The type initializer for '<namespace>.Program' threw an exception. (namespace stripped....)

Comment: Sorry I was not more explicit. [TypeInitializationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception.aspx) is simply a wrapper. The inner exception has all the goodies. Can you post at least the message from the inner exception?

Comment: Anything else that is static in your main class, i.e. 
private static SomeClass someField = new SomeClass();
?

Comment: I suspect something in your static initialization is doing this - something that has resources available when run from VS but not when run alone.  A classic example that has happened to me before is some app.config issues.

Comment: Well... the problem is that I can't see the inner exception. If I try to run it from the command line, I get an error message like "Application has generated an exception that could not be handled." I'm presented with 2 options: 1-terminate the application, 2-debug the application. If I debug the application, it opens a new VS 2005 instance and I can debug only the executable (no sources). If I debug it like that, I get the TypeInitializationException but without any details.

Answer (score 2):

Check out your code in static constructors. TypeInitializationException usually happens when there is an exception in static constructor, so type cannot be initialized. Code can work fine in IDE because it was started from different user with different security privileges. 
As a side note - I would avoid using of static constructors when it is possible.

Comment: Question: why should I avoid static constructors? And.. what's the difference between running from VS and running from windows as far as users and security privileges go?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the exception it sounds like either a static constructor or the initialization of a static field is throwing an unhanded exception here.  Given that the `Main` method is apparently not executing it's likely happening for a type which is referenced in the `Main` method and hence trying to be initialized by the CLR.

There are a couple of ways to track down what is causing this.  None of them are pretty

- Inspect the Main method of the program and analyze every Type in play and then analyze their static constructors to see which could be throwing
- Systematically comment out lines in the Main method to discover which one is causing the exception

Or alternatively when you run the program it should popup an error dialog.  At that point attach to the process and dig into the exception to see which type is causing the problem.

Comment: The first line in the Main method is a File.AppentAllText() with a debug message. This does not get written to the log file. :( Furthermore, if I try to attach with a debugger, I get another error: "Debugger::HandleIPCEvent, EventId = 0x201, Exception code=0xe06d7363, Eip=0x7c812afb"

Answer (score 0):

You will also get a `System.TypeInitializationException` when you have a error in a *.config file. Check the innerException for the LineNumber in that case.

Comment: The problem is that I don't see the inner exception. See comments bellow.

Comment: @Constantin When you start the app in debug mode at the start a popup window should open with exception (blabla) then click at "Get Details..".

Comment: when I start the application from VS 2005 (debug or release) I don't get any errors. The application runs fine. That's the problem I have: from VS it runs OK, from windows, I get errors.